# Origin (url) is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript

I know, this question has already been asked and answered, but it didn't help me.

When you visit my **[site](http://martijng.webklik.nl/page/kliksite)**, you will get the error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.criminalwar.nl/gangster/Avicii. Origin http://martijng.webklik.nl is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

(BTW Avicii is my playername on that game, so i changes every time)

How do I fix this? I had some bugs (around 10-20) and this is the last one but i dont know how to fix it..

It is a CSS based script.

Comment: CSS is not a scripting language.

Comment: This isn't a CSS problem, it's a security feature to not allow AJAX calls to other servers. Exactly what are you trying to do? There might be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

IF i understand correctly you are trying to do an ajax request on criminalwar.nl,

It is not working because the website is on a different domain. Try to add the request on your own domain or you can read more about [cross domain ajax](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/) here

And this is not a css problem it is a javascript and security feature